# rails 3.2 javascript_include_tag with 'cache => true' option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails 3.2.5. I used 'cache => true' option to combine javascript files. I wrote following code.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "a.js", "b.js", :cache => true %>
```

I get the following error when I try to load the page.

```
No such file or directory - Asset file not found at '/home/MyProjectPath/public/javascripts/home/MyProjectPath/app/assets/javascripts/a.js'
```

a.js and b.js are located in 'app/assets/javascripts/'.

If I use this code,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "a.js", "b.js" %>
```

It works fine. But they remain separate javascript files.

How can I merge javascript files using :cache option?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is :compress, not :cache . The error message you get is because the ":cache" option was removed, see the note in:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Answer (score 0):

Make your asset enable false in in application.rb file

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```